# scaffolding a view from model with subobjects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm wondering how to scaffold a view from a model, with sub objects.

For instance I have

```
Person (string name, DateTime birthdate, Address address)
Address (string street, int postalcode)
```

I scaffold this model to a view, I will have the name, the birthdate but not the street and the postal code, what a shame....

Is there is a way to use scaffolding in sub-object too?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not ideal, but I create a new method in the controller called scaffold(). I use it to generate the view for the sub-model.  Then I cut and paste the code it just made into the combined view.  Then you have to reference it like model.am.HouseNum if you were using an Address Model (am) as a sub-model.  Then you can delete the scaffold() method. Another idea is to use this newly created view and rename it and use it as a partial view.  I really wish the scaffolding would generate models within models automatically.  Maybe in a future version.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you work with a ViewModel you can use some thing like this:

your ViewModel:

```
    public class PersonViewModel
        {       
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }      
        [Display(Name = "Birthdate ")]
        public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "street")]
        public string street{ get; set; } 
        [Display(Name = "postalcode")]
        public int postalcode{ get; set; } 

        public PersonViewModel PersonFromModel() //you can put your parameters here
        {
        PersonViewModel  Person = new PersonViewModel()
        //your needed treatment to bind your viewModel 

        return PersonViewModel;
        }

        }
```

In your View just add:

```
@model YourNamespace.PersonViewModel
```

Then all what you have to do is to return the ViewModel in your cotroller ActionResult.

Comment: No, I want to keep the Address outside the Person! Otherwise it's a mess!